# Build java library with resources

Tags: java, android, build

I am trying to make android java library, but when I build my project in output jar library placed only java compiled classes, but no resources and assets.

Also my project contains native libraries, I need to include it in jar too.

[image]

**PS: I have connect my library project to another project.**

**PS2: I have find out that resources from library project (res, libs) compiles into apk file, but assets not. How to make assets compile too?**

Comment: Android SDK doesn't support export Android Library Project as a jar file yet.

Answer (score 1):

To export jar with resource file please follow the below steps.

```
1) Right Click on Project Folder
2) Then Click on Export
3) Click on Java -> Jar file.
4) It opens a Jar Export Dialog . Please ensure that Exported generated class file and       
   resource check-box is checked.
5) Then provide the export destination .
6) Finally click on finish button.
```

Answer (score 0):

In export menu for eclipse, you have a check box asking you for the inclusion of source files

Comment: I don't export my project. I connect my library project to other project.