# how to include resource file in distributed jar file?

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, resources

Did my search but don't see any answer on this.

I am building a jar as a SDK for distribution. The jar file got built successfully after I flag it as "is library" in build path.

Now the challenge is to also include my js library (js.zip) for distribution. I see js.zip got included in my .APK file after placing it under PROJECT_ROOT/res/raw. But I am not seeing it in the jar file via "jar tf my.jar". Doesn't make a diff if place my file in assets folder.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Lee

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html. http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html. Check the links

Answer (score 0):

> The jar file got built successfully after I flag it as "is library" in build path

That JAR is not designed for redistribution. It is an artifact of consuming an Android library project in a host project.

> Is this possible?

Android does not distribute Android resources in JARs at the time of this writing. *Maybe* this will become available with the Gradle-based build system currently under development.

You will need to distribute an Android library project, containing your resources, that also contains either your `src/` tree or a manually-constructed JAR for that code in `libs/`.

For example, here are a pair of fairly crude Ant tasks for this:

```
<target name="jar" depends="debug">
    <delete file="bin/CWAC-ColorMixer.jar" />
    <jar destfile="bin/CWAC-ColorMixer.jar" basedir="bin/classes" excludes="**/BuildConfig.class **/R*.class" />
</target>

<target name="dist-lib" depends="jar">
    <copy todir="/tmp/CWAC-ColorMixer/libs">
        <fileset dir="libs/" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="/tmp/CWAC-ColorMixer/res">
        <fileset dir="res/" />
    </copy>
    <copy file="bin/CWAC-ColorMixer.jar" todir="/tmp/CWAC-ColorMixer/libs" />
    <copy file="AndroidManifest.xml" todir="/tmp/CWAC-ColorMixer" />
    <copy file="build.xml" todir="/tmp/CWAC-ColorMixer" />
    <copy file="local.properties" todir="/tmp/CWAC-ColorMixer" />
    <copy file="project.properties" todir="/tmp/CWAC-ColorMixer" />
    <copy file="LICENSE" todir="/tmp/CWAC-ColorMixer" />
    <mkdir dir="/tmp/CWAC-ColorMixer/src" />
</target>
```

The first one creates the JAR file. The second one creates an Android library project in a temporary directory. This second Ant task in particular really needs improvement (e.g., configurable location, automatically ZIPping the result), but it works.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome book and your input here.

"You will need to distribute an Android library project, containing your resources, that also contains either your src/ tree"

- how to do so? 

" or a manually-constructed JAR for that code in libs/."

How can I manually constructe a JAR file? use AAPT?

Comment: how about this post? seems its doable.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902075/build-java-library-with-resources)

Comment: @user443461: "how to do so?" -- see edit. "How can I manually constructe a JAR file?" -- the same way people have been doing it in Java for the past 15 years or so. "how about this post?" -- besides being non-working gibberish?

Comment: Thanks @ commonsware.(the @ just not working). Thanks for the details!